# Slow BackgroundAudioPlayer on WP7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've created a audio player for Windows phone. It's a 7.1 project and I i run it on my Nokia Lumia 800 it takes maybe 6-7 sec before the audio plays. On my Lumia 920 its starts in less then 2 sec.

I've checked `PlayerState` and It never hits buffering (maybe it hits too fast :P), on both deviced they og straight to `Playing`.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: you'll have to give more detail - what type of data are you playing? what is the size and/or bitrate?